# Who first developed the idea of "sampling distributions"?

Tags: distributions, sampling, history

Who created sampling distributions? I have looked everywhere and I'm writing a paper, but, so far, all I've been able to come up with is the theory and the definition. Please help me find the who, what, when,and where.

Answer (score 8):

If you refer to the *term* "sampling distribution," information is hard to find.  But the *concept* is crucial to Jakob Bernoulli's (Switzerland) recognition that there is a distinction between that distribution and the population distribution itself, leading to his formulation (and proof) of a [Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).  (The Wikipedia article attributes the first statement of such a law to [Cardano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano) (Italy), who--among many other things--was an avid gambler and mathematician in the first half of the 16th century.)  Bernoulli's seminal work was published posthumously in 1713 as his *[ars conjectandi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Conjectandi)* but likely was developed in the late 1600's in response to [pioneering work by Pascal and Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points#Pascal_and_Fermat) (France) as recounted by Christian Huyghens (Netherlands) in an influential (and amazingly brief) 1657 textbook, *[de ratiociniis in ludo aleae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiaan_Huygens#Probability_theory)*.

For more background you can read a [brief accounting of some of this history](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1539-6924.2009.01271.x/full) I wrote in the form of a review of a Keith Devlin book, [The Unfinished Game](http://literati.net/Devlin/DevlinReviews.htm).

Comment: (+1) Let me just add the amazingly detailed an accurate [A History of Probability and Statistics and Their Applications before 1750](http://www.amazon.com/History-Probability-Statistics-Applications-before/dp/0471471291/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpi_2) by Anders Hald as a possible reference.

Comment: @NRH Thanks for the reminder: I was going to cite that for Bernoulli but forgot.  See the second chapter.  (I was unimpressed with some of the characterizations in the overview chapter, Chapter 1, however, so I do have some misgivings about this book.)